# Which packages/classes/methods/features will be removed after Scala 2.9?

Tags: scala, deprecated

I wonder if there is an overview somewhere, listing all the things scheduled for removal - not only the obvious things like case class inheritance - but also all the smaller places, were code/functionality will be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, no other answers yet, so I'll give it a try:

Language features:

- Case-to-case-class inheritance
- Case classes without parameter lists
- [`val` in for loops](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/36a95ecf471196e19ffd7e3c19a6103550d519c2)

Standard library items:

- Package `scala.dbc`
- Many things in `scala.swing`
- A few method like `sort`, `projection`, `first`, `elements`, ... in the collection library
- Methods like `append`, `counted`, `findIndexOf`, `readInto` in Iterator
- Methods `Array.fromFunction` and `new Array[Array[....]]`.
- Class `scala.CountedIterator`
- Class `scala.Cell`
- Package `scala.Math`
- The `Tuple` methods, `Integer`, `Character`, `Sequence`, `RandomAccessSequence` and a few annotation types in package object `scala`
- @serializable
- Quite a few methods in JavaConversions/JavaConverters
- Quite a few helper methods in `object List`
- case object `scala.concurrent.TIMEOUT`, class `scala.concurrent.MailBox`, object `scala.concurrent.pilib`
- package object `scala.runtime`
- A few other minor things

Comment: Would you mind providing links to where you got these informations?

Comment: Yes, I'll do that in a few minutes.

Comment: @pedrofurla Wasn't it just a case of `grep -r deprecated src/library`?

Comment: @daniel, "removed" is different than "deprecated". That is the reason I asked for links.

Comment: @pedrofurla Things deprecated get removed -- on Scala, if not on Java. I can readily identify at least half these items as deprecated, so, at one point, they'll get removed.